# Rails: Is it possible to show users with featured column on the homepage? Have to disable uglifier for chartkick to work on heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Routes.rb

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {
 registrations: 'users/registrations',
 sessions: 'users/sessions'
}
```

Custom Users Controller

```
def index
  @users = User.all
end 

def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

Home.html.erb

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <div class="each-user">
    <ul class="user-details">
      <li><%= user.given_name %></li>
      <li><%= user.surname %> <%= advisor.given_name %></li>
      <li><%= user.company %></li>
      <li><%= user.intro %></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

In my user model, I have a column where a User can be featured or not featured ( Boolean )
How may I change my code so that my homepage will show all the featured users?
Do I need to create an association for my homepage with User model? I know I am missing something but I am not really sure what it is as I keep getting "undefined method 'each' for nilNilClass, which would mean that I am not actually calling up the @User variable right?

And on another question if anyone happens to know, for my app deployment on heroku, I have to comment out/disable uglifier in the production.rb for chartkick to work on rails 5.2.1. Is there anyway to solve that, or if uglifier is really needed?

Comment: Please ask separate question for uglifer issue with correct error messages or logs you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On home page controller action you need to fetch only those users who are feature. You are already rendering `@users` variable. Just need to get correct data in `@users`. You can query for featured users by `where(featured: true)`.

```
def index
  @users = User.where(featured: true)
end
```

Alternatively it will be better if you can add scope in your model to get featured users:

Model user

```
scope :featured_users, -> { where(featured: true) }
```

Home controller

```
def index
  @users = User.featured_users
end
```

Comment: Do I need to retain the current index def if I want to show an index page of all users, and having to set another def? Maybe like a def index and for your solution do a def index-feature?

Comment: You can add filter on that page to filter out featured and all users. Or if you want to add separate page for featured users, you have to add new action `def` and corresponding html.

Comment: I think using `has_scope` gem is best solution for you. If you use it, you will not need to add new action for featured users. and you will can call scopes only by adding their params in your urls. for example, `/users` calls all users and `/users?featured_users` calls `featured_users` scope.

Comment: I have my homepage as home.html.erb, under a core_pages folder in views and a core_pages_controller.rb too.
Does this affect the routing? Because I have tried both suggested solutions and it is not working

Comment: Can you put your complete source code somewhere on git so that I can see what issues are there.

Comment: Ok...turns out my view file under core pages was Index.html.erb instead of index.html.erb.

2 days of searching and hair pulling wasted....

Comment: Actually not wasted, you learned that this kind of bug also possible. Next time you will easily trace if anything like this will appear.